# Why did Lucretia help Gannicus by giving him Ilithyia's information?

Tags: character, spartacus-tv

Why did Lucretia help Gannicus in the kidnapping of Ilithyia by giving him information about her departure? Lucretia hates Ilithyia, but still why does she help Gannicus? She is even telling Gaius Claudius Glaber to find out Ilithyia when he shows dis-interest. What is the reason for her conflicting steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After re-watching Lucretia's arc of the story it looks like Lucretia has became more insane and she just wants revenge from Ilithyia. Now her hate of Ilithyia is more than any other person. She shows nothing to Ilithyia directly but her steps always proves this. It's even shown by killing Ilithyia's child with a suicide in the end of Spartacus: Vengeance.